# Package structure for Spring MVC project with multiple sub projects using Maven

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, module, package

We want to create a spring MVC project using maven. We want to use just one project and, under it, have multiple sub-projects

What would be a good directory/package structure for the project for example

```
com
    company
        subproject_1
            controller
            doa
            service
            entity
        subproject_2
            controller
            dao
            service
            entity
```

or all files of sub projects in one project

```
com
    company
            controller
                all controllers of all sub projects 
            doa
                all dao of all sub projects
            service
            entity
```

depending on the experience which project structure would be maintainable if the project increases and sub projects keeps adding on

or suggestion of any other package structure?

also what is the naming standard used for directory
is it entity or domain? doa or persistence?

Comment: thanks Tereško for editing my question and making it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not following a multi-module project structure to group your sub-projects? It's a good coding practise widely adopted, recognised and easily manageable. Have a look at [this example](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html).

As far as the naming conventions goes that's personal preference but it's good idea to clearly maintain in package structure the different layers as you are saying from botton-top approach: the *dao* level, the *domain*, the *service* layer, the *controllers* and finally the *view*.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the *add to working set* option.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create maven multimodule project.
2. In each project two options:

   - package by feature
   - package by layer

   these options discussed here: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=205

My personal approach is to create in each maven module project packages by feature and some "util" packages used by "feature" packages.